# Deshabilitar como opcion un placeholder en laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Si tengo un select con:

```
{!!Form::label('tipoUsuario','(*)Rol',['class'=>'control-label'])!!} 
{!!Form::select('tipoUsuario',$tipoUsuario,null,['id'=>'tipoUsuario','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Seleccione Usuario','tabindex'=>'8'])!!}
```

¿Cómo hago para que el "placeholder" no me aparezca como una opción más en la lista de "tipo de usuarios", o que simplemente no se la pueda elegir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrias que hacerlo con la sintaxis normal de HTML no la sintaxis de LaravelCollective

Aqui el ejemplo

```html
<html>
 <select name="opciones">
   <option value="" hidden selected>Seleccione</option>
   <option value="1">Uno</option>
   <option value="2">Dos</option>
 </select>
</html>
```